# deleting component from array, vuejs removes wrong component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to be able to delete specific component from the array. I do this with splice and although that component definition is removed from array, vuejs removes wrong component. It allways removes the last added component.

Here is a fiddle that provides demonstration of that:

https://jsfiddle.net/wjjonm8n/

and here is video to show what is happening:

https://maxniko.tinytake.com/sf/MTg3NTI5NF82MDIxNDAx

here is some code:

```
Vue.component('row-component', {
    props: ["rowData", "uniqueId"],
    mounted: function() {
        console.log('mounting: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      console.log('removing: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            row component: {{rowData}}
            <button @click="$emit('delete-row')">Delete</button>
        </div>`
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <row-component v-for="(row, index) in rows" :row-data="row" :uniqueId="index" v-on:delete-row="deleteThisRow(index)"></row-component>
            <button @click="add()">add</button>
        </div> 
    `,
    data: {
        rows: ["line1", "line2", "line3", "line4", "line5"],

    },
    methods: {
            add() {
            this.rows.push('line'+(this.rows.length+1))
        },
        deleteThisRow: function(index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1)

            console.log(this.rows)
        }
    }
})
```

this function tells me what vuejs really removes:

```
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      console.log('removing: ' + this.uniqueId)
    }
```

it removes last added component if you look at what that console.log function prints. This is problem because on mount of each component I create listener for just that component:

```
this.$bus.$on('column-'+this.uniqueId+'-add-block', this.handlerMethod)
```

when vue removes last component, this event listener no longer works.

How can I solve this?

In my own application this is how I create child component:

```
let column = new Object()
column.uniqueId = this._uid+'-column-' + this.addedColumnCount
column.text = '1/2'
this.columnList.push(column)
this.addedColumnCount = this.addedColumnCount + 1
```

notice how I create uniqueId for component when I add it:

```
column.uniqueId = this._uid+'-column-' + this.addedColumnCount
```

when I try to delete a component it allways reports to me that the component with last added uniqueId is being removed.

```
    beforeDestroy: function() {
        this.$bus.$off('column-'+this.uniqueId+'-add-block', this.handlerMethod)
        console.log('removing: ' + this.uniqueId)
    },
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not have a `:key` binding to tell Vue which row goes with which component. Vue uses shortcuts to make the view look the same as the state of the viewmodel. If you add `:key="row"` to the `v-for`, it works.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjjonm8n/1/)

Comment: Hi, I've run into a problem now when I delete a row and that row has other rows created after it then all those rows are destryoed and recreated, here is a video of it: https://maxniko.tinytake.com/sf/MTg3NTc2M182MDIyMzI5 you can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/xk5yL3h8/ not sure why this is happening, I have moved delete button from the child component up the the parent and moved v-for into a div that holds the row-component. How can I avoid by deleting first row-component that all other row-components after it are destyroed as well and then recreated?